# Sys Call Fails in Python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, sys

I'm trying to allow custom monitoring by allowing custom system calls in a configuration file. It's a simple .ini file, but I'm having issues with the results I'm getting.

```
def sys_command(self, command):

    command_result = subprocess.check_output(["stat -c \"%s\" ./endpoint.py"], shell=True)
    return command_result
```

Above works fine.

```
def sys_command(self, command):

    command_result = subprocess.check_output([command], shell=True)
    return command_result
```

Above is what doesn't work when command is parsed from:

```
[directory]
file_size = "stat -c \"%s\" {file}"
```

Other functions handle the parsing, mapping, and string replacement for {file}. I've checked the command being passed in and it is valid. Here is the error I am getting.

```
"stat -c \"%s\" ./endpoint.py"
/bin/sh: stat -c "%s" ./endpoint.py: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monitor.py", line 147, in <module>
    print(test.custom_sys_command(test_focus_dict, "directory"))
  File "monitor.py", line 63, in custom_sys_command
    cmd_results = self.sys_command(parsed_cmd)
  File "monitor.py", line 70, in sys_command
    command_result = subprocess.check_output([command], shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['"stat -c \\"%s\\" ./endpoint.py"']' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

The first line is the command that was parsed out and passed in.

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['"stat -c "%s" ./endpoint.py"']' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

Above is the error I get if I remove the escape characters in the configuration file.

Comment: What is `command`? Is it a list also?

Comment: @tdelaney It is not. I used the format I found for checkoutput across a few examples.

Comment: so command = "stat -c \"%s\" ./endpoint.py" ?

Comment: Can you do `print(repr(command))` so we can see what is actually called?

Comment: As an aside, `os.stat` does the same thing and is generally preferred to a callout.

Comment: @tdelaney '"stat -c "%s" ./endpoint.py"'
Same as what can be seen in the first error in the last line. Looks like it's adding apostrophes somewhere. I'm assuming it's the actual checkoutput call.

Comment: Removing the quotes in the .ini file solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the quotes in the .ini file solved my issue.

"check_output didn't add the apostrophes, the .ini parser treated them as literal characters."

Comment: `check_output` didn't add the apostrophes, the .ini parser treated them as literal characters.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the help.